# What is an SLT1000 password encryption?

Tags: encryption, passwords

The sample password-encryption below.

{SLT1000}8kmbGwpGQRS0b8GOdAH4/Wrt8z4=

Could anyone identify what type of encryption is this?

Comment: Did you look in the manual for the SLT1000 switch? Anyway, it's probably SHA-1 (it's 160 bits).

Comment: Mike, you asked: "What is an SLT1000 password encryption?" But where are you getting this terminology from? As @forest  mentioned, this might be a base64-encoded SHA1 hash, but if this is the case then we would not call this "encryption," but rather "hashing." Can you provide a little more context?